# Can mongo handle multiple tailable cursors on the same collection

Tags: mongodb

We are using multiple tailable cursor on the same collection, it seems to be having deleterious effect on performance, is this expected? what can be done to improve performance with this setup or must it be changed?

Comment: Show us some code and numbers.

Comment: I don't think numbers or code are required. It's a pretty straight forward question of whether using multiple tailable cursors in Mongo is harmful or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple tailable cursors are fine. Indeed, many of Mongo's internal operations, like replication from a primary to multiple secondaries in a replica set, are implemented with tailable cursors.

Comment: any ideas why the processes would be so slow reading? other than the multiple cursor thing I haven't seen anything that would make it slow...

Comment: I can't answer your question with so little info about your application, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Performance seems to degrade when using multiple tailable cursors. As of the time of writing this is an open issue; see [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9580)